# Getting coordinates of drawn polygon using LeafletJS

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson

I'm new to LeafletJS. I have read many documents and followed examples. But I didn't have any information on how to solve a problem. I have a map and I use geoman.io tools. I draw a polygon with geoman tools. I want to click the layer and see the polygon's coordinates (GeoJSON formats). In all the examples I examined, the polygon was created in the line of code. I couldn't find any examples like this. I wonder what way should I examine

[image]

[image]

This is my code:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([40.97, 29.07], 13);


var basemap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


map.pm.addControls({
    position: 'topleft',
    drawCircle: true,
});



 /// 09.08
function makePopupContent(e){
    return `
        ${e.geometry.coordinates}   
    `;
}

 function onEachFeature(feature,layer){
    layer.bindPopup(makePopupContent(feature));

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pm:create` map event, which is fired when feature being drawn is created. Drawn layer is passed in event processing function as `e.layer`. Since this is Leaflet layer, you have to use `.toGeoJSON()` method to get corresponding GeoJSON feature.

When drawn layer is created, you have to attach `pm:update` event processing function to it, to update popup content if/when layer is edited.

Code could then look something like this:

```
function makePopupContent(feature){
  return `
    ${feature.geometry.coordinates}   
  `;
}

function setPupup(layer) {
  var feature = layer.toGeoJSON();
  var coords = makePopupContent(feature);
  layer.bindPopup(coords);
}

map.on('pm:create', function(e) {
  var layer = e.layer;
  setPupup(layer);
  layer.on('pm:update', function(e) {
    setPupup(e.layer);
  });
});
```

Comment: it is working thank you so much